# Extract top 20 records from a 2TB file that cannot fit in swap partition and memory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have a 2TB file on disk, and wish to numerical sort it by the second column.
(In fact, I only need top 20 records).

What I tried:

```
sort -k2nr 2tbfile.log | head -20
```

After few minutes running, I got an error - not enough disk space.

What's the best way to make this massive data sort?

Comment: do you have an alternate disk you can use for the sorting space? (`man sort` and search for temp space (or similar)). If not, then best to make code that just scans data for the top 20 items. Good luck.

Comment: split the file to n partitions, sort and pick top 20 from each, do a final sort and pick top 20 from the combined 20*n records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need the top 20 records, sorting the entire file uses a lot more memory (RAM or swap or temporary space) than necessary. There is an algorithm for extracting the top 20 (or however many you want) records, but I don't think there's a standard command line tool that implements it.

The algorithm (called “partial sorting”) uses a priority queue, which you could implement in any number of languages, including bash, but it would be painful in bash. The algorithm is in fact already implemented in the Python standard library, which makes for a short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import heapq
import sys

records = ((int(line.split()[1]), line) for line in sys.stdin)
top = heapq.nlargest(20, records)
for pair in top:
    print pair[1],
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
./top20 < 2tbfile.log
```

Comment: Unless python optimizes/combines the two step process, this might still run out of memory because `records` has to be filled fully first [or is the first statement a "lazy" eval?]. What about `top = heapq.nlargest(20, ((int(line.split()[1]), line) for line in sys.stdin))` to take advantage of the iterator?

Comment: `records` is a generator, not a list. It operates lazily.

Comment: Thanks. For scripts, I'm a perl guy, but I've learned a small amount of python  [just so I wouldn't be a total snob :-)] and was aware of generators. I just didn't recognize this as one.

Comment: [Sort::Key::Top](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Top) is the Perl version, but you have to download it from CPAN.